# Making a scala function tail-recursive when using yield?

Tags: scala, recursion, tail-recursion

I've got a function that's working;

```
def iterate(start: Seq[TestObj], sources: Seq[TestObj]): Seq[TestSeq] = {
  val currentTotal = start.foldLeft(TestObj(0, 0, 0))(_ + _)
  (for (s: TestObj <- sources) yield {
    val newTotal = currentTotal + s
    if (newTotal < target) {
      iterate(start :+ s, sources)
    } else {
      Seq(TestSeq(newTotal, target delta newTotal, (start :+ s).sortBy(e => (e.x, e.y, e.z))))
    }
  }).flatten
}
```

But I'd like to make this tail-recursive. I can not for the life of me figure out what the pattern is to do tail recursion while still maintaining my for/yield functionality.. Can one of the FP wizards around here point me in the right direction?

**UPDATE:** Thanks to the comments below, I've made some headway. My new test harness looks like the below. But it still bombs out.. Any hints to optimize are welcome, I'm pretty stumped..

```
case class TestObj(x: Int, y: Int, z: Int) {
  def +(that: TestObj): TestObj = {
    new TestObj(this.x + that.x, this.y + that.y, this.z + that.z)
  }

  def <(that: TestObj): Boolean = {
    this.x < that.x && this.y < that.y && this.z < that.z
  }

  def delta(that: TestObj) = {
    math.abs(this.x - that.x) + math.abs(this.y - that.y) + math.abs(this.z - that.z)
  }
}

case class TestSeq(score: TestObj, delta: Int, sequence: Seq[TestObj])

val sources = Seq(
  new TestObj(1, 2, 3), new TestObj(2, 3, 4), new TestObj(3, 4, 5),
  new TestObj(2, 3, 4), new TestObj(3, 4, 5), new TestObj(4, 5, 6),
  new TestObj(3, 4, 5), new TestObj(4, 5, 6), new TestObj(5, 6, 7))
val target = new TestObj(50, 60, 70)

def iterate(start: Seq[TestObj], maxItems: Int, sources: Seq[TestObj]): Set[TestSeq] = {
  val currentTotal = start.foldLeft(TestObj(0, 0, 0))(_ + _)

  if(maxItems == 0) {
    return Set(TestSeq(currentTotal, target delta currentTotal, start.sortBy(f => (f.x,f.y,f.z))))
  }

  sources.flatMap(s => {
    val newTotal = currentTotal + s
    if (newTotal < target) {
      iterate(start :+ s, maxItems - 1, sources)
    } else {
      Set(TestSeq(newTotal, target delta newTotal, start :+ s))
    }
  }).toSet
}

val possibleCombinations = iterate(Seq(new TestObj(0, 0, 0)), 10, sources)
val usableCombinations = possibleCombinations.map(c => TestSeq(c.score, c.delta, c.sequence.drop(1)))

println(usableCombinations)
usableCombinations.toSeq.sortBy(f => f.delta).foreach(uc => {
  println(s"${uc.delta}: ${uc.sequence}")
})
```

Comment: You function seems to produce a lot of identical sequences (am I right in that?) Is this intended? Do you want to use tail recursion to make it run faster? Because at the moment there seem to be much worse performance problems than non-tail recursion (recalculating the total on each call, appending elements to the end may be inefficient, building the whole sequence of sequences instead of doing it lazily).

Comment: `iterate` as it stands can not be turned into a tail-recursive function. Also `(for (s <- sources) yield { ... }).flatten` can be written as `sources.flatMap { ... }`. Maybe you can show us the problem which you are trying to solve ?

Comment: The duplicates are not wanted -- in fact i blow them away later, so I welcome a better solution. The main reason for tail recursion is this currently dies with out-of-memory when fed a lot of data. I'm basically trying to solve a variation of multi-variant knapsack. Given a few sets of integers (tuples) like (1,2,3), find all combinations of sources where each number adds up to target. (or is close) I.e. (1,2,3) + (1,2,3) == (2,4,6) would be a match with delta 0. (1,2,3) + (2,2,3) == (2,4,6) + (1 delta)

Comment: Yes, the problem is not with non-tail recursiveness, but with a *huge* size of the resulting `Seq`. The recursion itself is not too deep here, compared to the result size. If there is enough data for the stack size to become a problem, it would probably take millenia to compute anyway, so that's not an issue. Storing duplicates in the result boosts its size a lot. And I believe that you can't avoid generating duplicates for multi-knapsack, not with trivial algorithms anyway. And you can't make it lazy, since you must filter duplicates.

Comment: As a possible solution try to change the result type for `Set[TestSeq]` instead of `Seq` (and of course swap the `Seq(TestSeq(newTotal ...` line for `Set( ...`). This will avoid storing duplicates in the first place. Also, don't forget to increase the heap size when you run Java. It's an NP problem, so it quickly becomes intractable even for moderate input sizes anyway.

Comment: Set won't work here.. It's perfectly acceptable to solve hit a target of, say (3,3,3) with 3 copies of (1,1,1)..

Comment: @XeroxDucati Set of TestSeq. It can contain a TestSeq with 3 copies of (1,1,1), but it can't contain 2 same TestSeqs

Comment: @Kolmar realized that's what you meant a few minutes ago :) I'm updating with the latest test code, but unfortunately it still vomits..